# How do I extend hover area of button so drop down is still triggered?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have this code (W3 schools I know, am making a mockup):

HTML:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

#logo {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 16.5px;
  padding-top: 7.5px;
}

.right .si {
  border: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.right .su {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #00b22d;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
  padding-bottom: 12.5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Navbar container */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Links inside the navbar */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #808080;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  padding-top: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  color: black;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #808080;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 17.5px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

.column p {
  float: none;
  color: #808080;
  padding-left: 26px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

/* Style links inside the columns */
.column a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.column h4 {
    font-family: Verdana;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.column img {
    height: 150px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" id="logo">Middle.ly</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Explore
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6" fill="none" role="img" class="icon caret" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
        <path d="M1 1L5.07223 5.1517L9.23083 1" stroke="black"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Find Work
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6" fill="none" role="img" class="icon caret" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
        <path d="M1 1L5.07223 5.1517L9.23083 1" stroke="black"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    |
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Hiring Designers?
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="6" viewBox="0 0 10 6" fill="none" role="img" class="icon caret" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
        <path d="M1 1L5.07223 5.1517L9.23083 1" stroke="black"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/1020693-200.png">
          <h4>Page name</h4>
          <p>Page description</p>
        </a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <button class="si">Sign in</button>
    <button class="su">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ProxyCode/56vsja70/1/

The code all works great apart from the fact that there's a small gap in between where the button is and where the dropdown starts meaning the dropdown disappears before the user can hover over it and make it stay in place. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS file, change class ".dropdown-content" to use:

```
margin-top: 0;
```

Rather than 17.5px.

With this, you're adding space between your dropdown-content and dropbtn.

Comment: While this works is there any way the space can remain? I need the drop down to line up with the bottom of the header. Thank you for the reply though

Comment: Yes, you can also include 'padding-top: 17.5px' to .dropdown-content. This should accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove only one property margin-top: 17.5px; from .dropdown-content CSS.